# Byte array conversion clarification?

Tags: python, hex, byte

I am trying to create byte array of three bytes.

```
data = 0xee55
bi = bytearray(3)
bi[0] = 0x01  # register for speed
bi[1] = data & 0xFF # first byte of speed data
bi[2] = (data >> 8) & 0xFF  # second byte of speed data
```

Bytes 0 to 2 are correct but once displayed value of bi

```
print(bi)
```

bytearray(b'\x01U\xee')

Why is that? How to for instance convert bi back to binary.

I think that it is simple question for digital person, but my background is analogue.

Thank you for an advice.

Comment: The data you have written into `bi` is held there correctly. If *you* want to *see* the data in a form you will recognise, you can do: `print(bi.hex())` which will output: `0155ee`

Comment: The reason you see a 'U' in there is because whenever possible, print will try to convert byte values to ASCII characters. It just so happens that your second byte has the value of 85 which translates to 'U'.